# PHP Sort Array or Arrays by one field with 4 different values

Tags: php

I have the following PHP creating an array of arrays:

);

I want to be able to sort this array by the field "profileStatus"

The catch is the field has 4 values and I want to sort it in this order:

- online
- away
- busy
- offline

The next field to sort by is heartbeat (this is a MySQL date).

I've looked at usort() and multiarraysort() by they don't appear to sort by different values of a field - I could be wrong.

I played with the following with no luck:

```
function cmpDistance($a, $b) {
    return ($a['distance'] - $b['distance']);
}
```

Any ideas - point in the right direction - would be greatly appreciated :)

thx

Comment: What is the next variable that you organize by? Basically, if you have two "onlines," does it matter which comes first?

Comment: Heartbeat is the other field to sort by - its a MySQL DateTime value. thaanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this perfectly using usort(), so you were on the right way. However your usort() callback function needs to be a bit more enhanced.

```
<?php

// Let's assign a value to each profile status
$values = array('online' => 1, 'away' => 2, 'busy' => 3, 'offline' => 4);

usort($this->initializeTodayMembersOnlineArray, function($a, $b) use ($values) {
    return $values[$a['todayInitializeProfileStatus']] - $values[$b['todayInitializeProfileStatus']];
});

?>
```

Now if the callback function is called, the 1-4 values will be properly evaluated and return a negative, 0 or positive number, effectively sorting your array.

Comment: I'm getting this response - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'cmp' (T_STRING) - is the array or arrays causing an issue here